# In C#, how to instantiate a passed generic type inside a method?

Tags: c#, generics

How can I instantiate the type T inside my `InstantiateType<T>` method below?

I'm getting the error: **'T' is a 'type parameter' but is used like a 'variable'.**:

### (SCROLL DOWN FOR REFACTORED ANSWER)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestGeneric33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Container container = new Container();
            Console.WriteLine(container.InstantiateType<Customer>("Jim", "Smith"));
            Console.WriteLine(container.InstantiateType<Employee>("Joe", "Thompson"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        public T InstantiateType<T>(string firstName, string lastName) where T : IPerson
        {
            T obj = T();
            obj.FirstName(firstName);
            obj.LastName(lastName);
            return obj;
        }

    }

    public interface IPerson
    {
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Customer : IPerson
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee : IPerson
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### REFACTORED ANSWER:

Thanks for all the comments, they got me on the right track, this is what I wanted to do:

```
using System;

namespace TestGeneric33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Container container = new Container();
            Customer customer1 = container.InstantiateType<Customer>("Jim", "Smith");
            Employee employee1 = container.InstantiateType<Employee>("Joe", "Thompson");
            Console.WriteLine(PersonDisplayer.SimpleDisplay(customer1));
            Console.WriteLine(PersonDisplayer.SimpleDisplay(employee1));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Container
    {
        public T InstantiateType<T>(string firstName, string lastName) where T : IPerson, new()
        {
            T obj = new T();
            obj.FirstName = firstName;
            obj.LastName = lastName;
            return obj;
        }
    }

    public interface IPerson
    {
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonDisplayer
    {
        private IPerson _person;

        public PersonDisplayer(IPerson person)
        {
            _person = person;
        }

        public string SimpleDisplay()
        {
            return String.Format("{1}, {0}", _person.FirstName, _person.LastName);
        }

        public static string SimpleDisplay(IPerson person)
        {
            PersonDisplayer personDisplayer = new PersonDisplayer(person);
            return personDisplayer.SimpleDisplay();
        }
    }

    public class Customer : IPerson
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Employee : IPerson
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for shifting to a better design pattern.

Comment: +1 for extremely neatly typed code, a rarity.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Declare your method like this:

```cs
public string InstantiateType<T>(string firstName, string lastName) 
              where T : IPerson, new()
```

Notice the additional constraint at the end.  Then create a `new` instance in the method body:

```
T obj = new T();
```

Comment: I've been writing C# for years with some heavy generic typing abuse in my days, and I NEVER knew you could define a constraint like this to instantiate a generic type. Many thanks!

Comment: very very nice!!

Comment: what if NO specified type, Is that possible?

Answer (score 34):

Couple of ways.

Without specifying the type must have a constructor:

```
T obj = default(T); //which will produce null for reference types
```

With a constructor:

```
T obj = new T();
```

But this requires the clause:

```
where T : new()
```

Comment: The first one will assign null rather than create an instance for reference types.

Comment: Yep. You need to use reflection to create types without a default constructor, default(T) is null for all reference types.

Comment: Yep absolutely, included for completeness really.

Answer (score 15):

To extend on the answers above, adding `where T:new()` constraint to a generic method will require T to have a public, parameterless constructor.

If you want to avoid that - and in a factory pattern you sometimes force the others to go through your factory method and not directly through the constructor - then the alternative is to use reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance...`) and keep the default constructor private. But this comes with a performance penalty, of course.

Comment: It's not the first time people downvote "all other answers" :)

Comment: I'll admit to sometimes scurrilously not upvoting 'competing' answers until the dusgt has settled on a question :D I guess (non-points) karma will sort them out!

Answer (score 8):

you want **new** T(), but you'll also need to add `, new()` to the `where` spec for the factory method

Comment: i bumped it back up, I understood it, helped, it seems in general people like posted code better than descriptions here

Comment: correct but your answer is admittedly a bit on the short side ;)

Answer (score 6):

A bit old but for others looking for a solution, perhaps this could be of interest: http://daniel.wertheim.se/2011/12/29/c-generic-factory-with-support-for-private-constructors/

Two solutions. One using Activator and one using Compiled Lambdas.

```
//Person has private ctor
var person = Factory<Person>.Create(p => p.Name = "Daniel");

public static class Factory<T> where T : class 
{
    private static readonly Func<T> FactoryFn;

    static Factory()
    {
        //FactoryFn = CreateUsingActivator();

        FactoryFn = CreateUsingLambdas();
    }

    private static Func<T> CreateUsingActivator()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        Func<T> f = () => Activator.CreateInstance(type, true) as T;

        return f;
    }

    private static Func<T> CreateUsingLambdas()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        var ctor = type.GetConstructor(
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance |
            BindingFlags.NonPublic,
            null, new Type[] { }, null);

        var ctorExpression = Expression.New(ctor);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(ctorExpression).Compile();
    }

    public static T Create(Action<T> init)
    {
        var instance = FactoryFn();

        init(instance);

        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use reflection to fetch the object's constructor and instantiate that way:

```
var c = typeof(T).GetConstructor();
T t = (T)c.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a factory class to build your object with compiled lamba expression: The fastest way I've found to instantiate generic type.

```
public static class FactoryContructor<T>
{
    private static readonly Func<T> New =
        Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression.New(typeof (T))).Compile();

    public static T Create()
    {
        return New();
    }
}
```

Here is the steps I followed to set up the benchmark.

Create my benchmark test method:

```
static void Benchmark(Action action, int iterationCount, string text)
{
    GC.Collect();
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    action(); // Execute once before

    sw.Start();
    for (var i = 0; i <= iterationCount; i++)
    {
        action();
    }

    sw.Stop();
    System.Console.WriteLine(text + ", Elapsed: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

I've also tried using a factory method:

```
public static T FactoryMethod<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

For the tests I've created the simplest class :

```
public class A { }
```

The script to test:

```
const int iterations = 1000000;
Benchmark(() => new A(), iterations, "new A()");
Benchmark(() => FactoryMethod<A>(), iterations, "FactoryMethod<A>()");
Benchmark(() => FactoryClass<A>.Create(), iterations, "FactoryClass<A>.Create()");
Benchmark(() => Activator.CreateInstance<A>(), iterations, "Activator.CreateInstance<A>()");
Benchmark(() => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (A)), iterations, "Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (A))");
```

> **Results over 1 000 000 iterations:**
>
> new A(): 11ms
>
> FactoryMethod A(): 275ms
>
> FactoryClass A .Create(): 56ms
>
> Activator.CreateInstance A (): 235ms
>
> Activator.CreateInstance(typeof (A)): 157ms

**Remarks**: I've tested using both **.NET Framework 4.5 and 4.6** (equivalent results).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a function to Instantiate the type

```
public T InstantiateType<T>(string firstName, string lastName) where T : IPerson, new()
    {
        T obj = new T();
        obj.FirstName = firstName;
        obj.LastName = lastName;
        return obj;
    }
```

you could have done it like this

```
T obj = new T { FirstName = firstName, LastName = lastname };
```

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked. The real problem here was that he needed to create a new instance of the generic class.  Perhaps it was unintended, but it seems like you are saying that using an initializer would solve the original problem, but it does not.  The `new()` constraint is still needed on the generic type for your answer to work.

Comment: If you are trying to be helpful and suggest that the initializer is a useful tool here, then you should post that as a comment, not another answer.