# How to pass class instance to a static method?

Tags: c#

I actually managed this creating this code:

```
class Foo{
    public void test(){
         Keyboard.input(this);
    }

    public void menu(){
          Console.WriteLine("This is a menu");
    }
}

class Keyboard{
     public static string input(object class_name){
           new class_name().menu(); //call from dynamic object the method
     }
}
```

How you can see I have a class called `Foo` this contains the method `test` that read some input from the user keyboard, essentially this method allow me to recognize if the user press a particular key the code call the method menu. In this example it's just called the method `menu`. Now I pass the instance of the class `Foo` to the `Keyboard` class that have a static method called `input`, this method should create a new instance of the passed class and call the `menu` method. But I actually got an error on this line:

```
new class_name()
```

> object is an object but is used as a type

what I did wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In C#, how to instantiate a passed generic type inside a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658951/in-c-how-to-instantiate-a-passed-generic-type-inside-a-method)

Comment: You have to create an instance of that object before you can call a method from it. you can't `new <object>().<methodcall>()`.

Comment: you can create an interface which will have a method signature for `menu` then inherit `Foo` from that interface and use that interface instead of `object` also remove the new keyword when calling the `menu` on the parameter

Comment: you are passing `this` which is correct and `this` keyword is used to get the instance of the containing class. In your case it will be the object of `Foo`

Comment: @vc74 I think you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36199416/3917161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `class_name` is an instance of class not a type, you should cast it to `Foo` type and call the function.

Change

```
new class_name().menu();
```

to

```
((Foo)class_name).menu();
```

**Update**

If you wish it to use on multiple classes, you should create an [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/87d83y5b.aspx) for them to inherit.

```
// All classes passed into 'Keyboard.Input' should inherit this interface
interface IMenu
{
    public void menu();
}

class Foo : IMenu
{
    public void test()
    {
        Keyboard.input(this);
    }
    public void menu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is a menu");
    }
}
```

and change the lines from

```
public static string input(object class_name)
{
    new class_name().menu(); //call from dynamic object the method
}
```

to

```
public static string input(IMenu class_name)
{
    ((IMenu)class_name).menu();
    return "Something you want to return";
}
```

Comment: but I don't know the name of the class. For this I have created this method, 'cause I have several classes that have the menu method, calling this `data` method I need to call the `menu` function available in the instance class passed. This instance is available inside the `class_name`.

Comment: just a question: why I need to extend `IMenu` to `Foo` class?

Comment: @Sandokan So that the `Keyboard` class can know the object passed in has the `menu()` function.

Comment: So is a declaration of the method? If I remove the extension `IMenu` the `Keyboard` class can't locate it, right?

Comment: @Sandokan Of course you should keep it, the `Foo` class need to inherit it too. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use generic method with `new` constraint and pick `menu` method into base abstract class:

```
public abstract class MenuClass
{
    public abstract void menu();
}

class Keyboard
{
    //if you can pass class name
    public static string input<TClassName>() where TClassName : MenuClass, new()
    {
        new TClassName().menu();
    }

    //if you can not pass class name
    public static string input<TClassName>(TClassName obj) where TClassName : MenuClass, new()
    {
        new TClassName().menu(); //if you want to create new instance
        obj.menu(); //if you want to use already existing object
    }
}
```

You can use first method if you can pass required class name, and if you cannot - use the second method without generic parameter:

```
Keyboard.input(yourObj);
```

Compiler will automatically get type parameter from usage

---

**UPDATE**

As you have not abstract classes or interfaces you should cast your object to required class before calling method:

```
 public static string input(object class_name){
        if (class_name as Foo != null)
        {
            ((Foo)class_name).menu();
        }
 }
```

or if you do not know the input type of an object and can not use generics, but you should to create new instance of the same class, use reflection:

```
 public static string input(object class_name){
        if (class_name != null)
        {
            Foo newObj = Activator.CreateInstance(class_name.GetType());
            newObj.menu();
        }
 }
```