# Why does creating an instance of a generic type work like this?

Tags: c#, generics

Use case:

```
class A {};

class B : A {};

class C : A {};

class Foo <T>: where T : A {
...

// T bar = new T(arg1, arg2);

...

}

class FooB: Foo<B> {...}

class FooC: Foo<C> {...}
```

I want to use children of class `A` in corresponding children of `Foo`. `FooA` and `FooB` have some extra logic that only works with `A` and `B` respectively. As a side note, I hope this is the right way to do this because I feel like this is a common scenario but I haven't seen any info on it elsewhere.

---

Shouldn't the compiler be able to see that based on the constraint that `T` has to be a child of `A` what constructor is appropriate? I am currently able to just add a `new()` constraint and then call methods on the newly created object. This was also done [here in a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658951/in-c-how-to-instantiate-a-passed-generic-type-inside-a-method). What I don't understand is why the compiler can call methods on an unknown type but can't instantiate it. Especially with constraints that should allow it to do so.

For example, why can I do something like:

```
class Foo <T>: where T: A, new() {
...
T bar = new T()
bar.Construct(arg1, arg2);
...
```

Comment: unfortunately compilers are not smart enough to figure out what constructor is needed to be called, you need to tell that

Comment: methods are implemented in interfaces. so when you say `why the compiler can call methods on an unknown type` is wrong. because type is not unknown. there are constraints to interfaces, classes. so its not weird that compiler can call method on generic type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine the next classes:

```
public class A
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    public A(int someInt)
    {
        this.SomeInt = someInt;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
}
```

This will not compile since, there is not public default constructor on `A` and the compiler doesn't know how to initialize `A` from `B`.
Constructors are not inherited in C#:
From Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/tour-of-csharp/classes-and-objects):

> Unlike other members, instance constructors are not inherited, and a class has no instance constructors other than those actually declared in the class. If no instance constructor is supplied for a class, then an empty one with no parameters is automatically provided.

Surely, after we'll fix it, we can call on the `SomeInt` property from the `B` class. That's after all what inheritance is.

So, for your question - the compiler doesn't know which constructors will be defined for the `T` type at run-time. However it knows, since its a sub-class  of `A` which method/properties it can access.