# Instantiate an instance of a generic type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a specialized generic collection class which will be used to hold collections of many different types of objects. Once the collection is created, I need to instantiate the collection's items. I am having the darnedest time getting this to work. There must be a simple solution I am missing.

Here is a sample class which kind of illustrates what I am trying to do and the warnings/errors I am bumping up against.

```
// Note: T may either a string or other reference type that supports IEnumerable. 
public class Foo<T>
{
    private List<T> fooBarList = new List<T>();

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar1<T>();
        Bar2<T>();
        Bar3<T>();
    }

    public void Bar1<T>()
    {
        // Error Message: Argument 1 cannot convert from 'T...' to 'T...'
        T t = default;
        fooBarList.Add(t);
    }

    public void Bar2<T>() where T : IEnumerable, new()
    {
        // Error Message: T must be a non-abstract type with public
        // parameterless constructor in order to use it as a parameter 'T'
        // in the generic type or method 'Foo<T>.Bar2<T>()

        fooBarList.Add(new T());
    }

    public void Bar3<T>() where T : IEnumerable, new()
    {
        // Error Message: Argument 1 cannot convert from 'T...' to 'T...'
        T t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        fooBarList.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Side note: This particular code is in a particularly performance-critical part of my application--you know, the 3% Donald Knuth talks about needing to actually be optimized. This really does need to be fast because it will get called millions of times per application execution. I would not be at all enthusiastic about using reflection (e.g. Activator.CreateInstance() here) if there is any other alternative. (For now, even that does not seem to be working for me.) I would much rather have the compiler resolve the data type at compile time.

This question was already answered in the link below, but none of the approaches seem to be working for me. What am I missing?

[In C#, how to instantiate a passed generic type inside a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658951/in-c-how-to-instantiate-a-passed-generic-type-inside-a-method)

FYI, I am using .NET Core 2.2 Beta and .NET Standard 2.0 on a Windows 10 machine running Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise Preview.

Comment: `public void Bar1<T>()`... should be `public void Bar1()`, these methods should not be generic but rather use the classe's generic type

Comment: I think @vc74 has the correct solution or close to it.  You need to declare the where clause on T (specifying that T is a collection and is new-able) up at the class level, and then remove the `<T>` bits at the function level.

Comment: You've already included a restraint that the type has a default constructor when you said `where T : new()`, so that means you can safely do `var myT = new T();` Just make sure you add that constraint wherever you need it. You can define `T` at the class level (and include the constraint there) if you want it to be the same everywhere.

Comment: You're getting a lot of answers below that require the concrete type of T to have a public parameterless constructor.  Is this a satisfactory constraint for your purposes?

Comment: Also, whatever your *actual* problem is (foobar examples are seldom sufficiently illustrative), could it be solved by simply using `dynamic`?

Comment: @Anthony Gatlin Are you trying to automatically create instances of types that don't have default (parameterless) constructor? If so, it just is impossible, how could the compiler infer the constructor parameters?

Comment: By the way, the reason for the oddball "Can't convert T to T" messages is likely because you have two T's declared, one at the class level, and one at the function level

Comment: @RobertHarvey Dynamic would not be sufficient. I need concrete types. My actual data structure is more like List<List<T>>. Sometimes T is a string, but often it can be a type with its own hierarchy of of collections beneath. The FooBar example here actually was sufficient to demonstrate my misapplication of Generic structures in C# and to allow others to create my erroneous understanding--which  you all have done superbly.

Comment: @vc74 Yes, there are some types, such as string, which may be instantiated. I don't believe .NET views strings as having a parameterless constructor--even though you don't provide a constructor when you initialize a string. I could be wrong on my assertion as to what .NET is expecting here. I am just offering my possibly flawed understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `List<T>` already has all you need except a method to create a new instance and add it, which could be added as extension methods:

```
public static ICollectionExtensions
{
    public static AddNew<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
        where T : new()
    {
        var newItem = new T();
        collection.Add(newItem);
    }

    ...
}
```

which can be used like this:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.AddNew();
```

Answer (score 1):

This compiles:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : IEnumerable, new()
{
    private List<T> fooBarList = new List<T>();

    public Foo()
    {
        Bar1();
        Bar2();
        Bar3();
    }

    public void Bar1()
    {
        T t = default(T);
        fooBarList.Add(t);
    }

    public void Bar2()
    {
        fooBarList.Add(new T());
    }

    public void Bar3() 
    {
        T t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        fooBarList.Add(t);
    }
}
```

Note that the only declaration of `T` is up at the class level, both the `<T>` part and the `where` part.

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work unless the concrete type of T has a public, parameterless constructor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's what the [`new()` constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint) means...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, but that's where `where T: new()` comes in

Comment: In the OP's example, they are citing the error message `T must be a non-abstract type with public  parameterless constructor in order to use it as a parameter 'T'`, so I assume they want to use it with a type that isn't so ordained.

Comment: But, if you code it the way I did, there are no errors or warning when it's compiled

Comment: You're missing the point.  A specialized collection of the type the OP is describing must be usable with *any* type, not just the ones that happen to have a public parameterless constructor.  You can't even use this with strings.

Comment: If he wants to do what his code says he wants to do (create objects, etc) then he needs a new() constraint.  My point is that he can't just constrain T on the functions where he wants to do the object creation.  It's the same T for the whole class, the constraint has to be at the class level

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying.  Overall, I don't find this idea particularly compelling.  If it's a collection that's supposed to hold objects of different types, then why would it be constrained to a type T?