# Instantiate a type passed in the method

Tags: c#, types

I've been looking but I think this is the kind of question I don't know the right concept for to find. I want to pass a Type to a method and have the method create a new variable of that type. I need the new variable to be instantiated with it's default value. I then need to save that instance in a list of object (not shown for clarity). The code runs but I get a null as the return value. I expect a instantiated instance of that type that is not null. I will be using this method for multiple Types. I am hoping there is a flexible way to do this rather than hardcoding for a new type each time I need a new type.

This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658951/in-c-how-to-instantiate-a-passed-generic-type-inside-a-method) look like it is workable for only one type "where T : IPerson, new()". I need this to be workable for multiple types - string, double, List, ...

I started with:

```
public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name)
    {
        T newVar = default;
        //Do some stuff with newVar
        return newVar;
    }
```

I tried (and get null):

```
    public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name) where T : List<string>
    {
        T newVar = default;
        //Do some stuff with newVar
        return newVar;
    }
```

Comment: " I then need to save that type in a list of object " you want to save the type? or the instance of that object? " The code runs but I get a null as the return value." what do you expect? null is the default value for a list. do you expect a new instance of that type?

Comment: This does not make sense to me. did you want to do something like `public static List<T> DoSomeStuff<T>(string name)
{
    var list = new List<T>();
    //Do some stuff.
    return list;
}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this with a `new()` generic constraint.

```
public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name) 
    where T : new(), List<string>
    //        ^ here
```

Comment: Probably you need to add also that _default(T)_ should be replaced by _new T();_