# Creating a generic method that accepts a type and returns an instance of that type

Tags: c#, types

I want to pass a Type to a method and have the method create and return a new variable of that type. I need the new variable to be instantiated with it's default value rather than pass back a null. While in the method I then need to save that instance in a list of object (not shown for clarity). My code below runs but I get a null as the return value. I expect an instantiated instance of that type that is not null. I will be using this method for multiple Types (string, double, List, ...etc). I am hoping there is a flexible way to do this rather than hardcoding for a new type each time I need a new type.

I do see this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658951/in-c-how-to-instantiate-a-passed-generic-type-inside-a-method). This looks like it is workable but only for one type (IPerson):

```
public string InstantiateType<T>(string firstName, string lastName) 
          where T : IPerson, new()
```

in the example in the question. I was hoping for a more generic solution workable for multiple types - string, double, List, ...etc. Whatever is passed to to the method.

I started with:

```
public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name)
    {
        T newVar = default;
        //Do some stuff with newVar
        return newVar;
    }
```

I tried (and get null):

```
    public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name) where T : List<string>
    {
        T newVar = default;
        //Do some stuff with newVar
        return newVar;
    }
```

I created a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69376804/instantiate-a-type-passed-in-the-method) earlier today that was quickly closed as a duplicate. I did just find this answer that seems to work. Perhaps this is my answer?

```
public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name)
{
    T newVar = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    return newVar;
}
```

Comment: `This looks like it is workable but only for one type (IPerson)` - you can remove the `IPerson` constraint. Also, take a look at the [docs for `Activator.CreateInstance<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance__1). It says that `new T()` actually just calls `CreateInstance<T>()` and "there is no use for the CreateInstance<T>() generic method in application code"

Comment: Now it is *slowly* closed as duplicate... So should be all good. I would recommend waiting to ask a question till you know if something is an answer or not - at this point you seem to be undecided on what you want otherwise the question would spell out why approach shown (with `Activator.CreateInstance`) is not what you need.

Answer (score 1):

> I started with ... `default(T)`

The `default` keyword in C# behaves differently depending on the type in question. Value types will use their default value (which may be the intended behavior); however, reference types' default value is `null`, which is not the intended behavior.

> I tried (and get null) ...

Once again, `default` will not return an instance of type `T` when `T` is a reference type.

> I did just find this answer that seems to work. Perhaps this is my answer?

You're right. `Activator.CreateInstance()` is the easiest way to create an instance of an arbitrary type. It's worth noting that that type must have a parameterless constructor (e.g. `new MyClass()`), or you must provide arguments for a valid constructor.

To enforce that `Activator.CreateInstance()` requires a parameterless constructor, you can constrain `T` to `new()`:

```
public static T DoSomeStuff<T>(string name) where T : new()
{
    T newVar = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    return newVar;
}
```