# How to instantiate a generic type in base class?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have a built an XML parser which parses different types of products. The parser code is common for all product types (it deserializes the XML into Product type)

So I have created a generic base class called `XmlParser`

```
public abstract class XmlParser<TProduct> where TProduct : ProductBase
{
    public abstract TEntity Instanciate();
        
    private string _parserName;

    public XmlParser(string parserName)
    {
        _parserName = parserName;
    }

    public List<TProduct>Parse()
    {
        TEntity product = Instanciate(); // <-- I need to instantiate the Generic type here 
        // deserialize XML into product
    }
}
```

and a derived class:

```
public class CarXmlParser : XmlParser<Car>
{
    public CarXmlParser() : base("CarParse") {}

    public override Car Instanciate()
    {
        return new Car();
    }
}
```

`Car` is product type and is derived from `ProductBase`

In the base class, I need to instantiate `TProduct`. The only way I could do this was by creating an abstract method in the base class: `public abstract TEntity Instanciate();`. Obviously the child has to implement it.

Is there an easier way to instantiate the generic type? I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658951/in-c-how-to-instantiate-a-passed-generic-type-inside-a-method) where they use `new T` constraint for the same purpose, however I was not able apply it to my example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has a *default constructor*,  add the [New Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint), and `new` it up

> The new constraint specifies that a type argument in a generic class
> declaration must have a public parameterless constructor. To use the
> new constraint, the type cannot be abstract.

**Example**

```
public abstract class XmlParser<TProduct> 
    where TProduct : ProductBase, new()

...

public List<TProduct>Parse()
{
    var product = new TProduct();

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if it doesn't have `new()` constraint you can use the following:

```
 Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
```